# Keeping div stuck on position, but let footer kick it up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The title might sound strange but I want to achieve something with a menu.

I mocked it in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93eza485/23) because an example tells more then 1000 words :)

The page-content (yellow) scrolls underneath the header(red). The menu on the left (blue) should stay in place. Which could be accomplished by using `position: fixed`. But...

If we scroll further, the footer comes into view. If we scroll even further the size of `main` (between red and green lines) becomes smaller then the height of the blue-navigation element. I now want the blue-element to be pushed up underneath the red-header element.

So in essence the blue element should stick to its current position, but it should be pushed up by the footer if the height between the red line and the green line becomes smaller then the height of the nav element.

How would I be able to make the blue-box stick **but also let it be pushed up by the green footer?**

Comment: I'm aware of the help pages. And I therefore included a JSfiddle with a complete and minimal code example/mock of the project I'm working in. 
I also have a concrete problem: How to make the blue box be bumped up by the green-footer.

Comment: The larger issue is that the fiddle shows absolutely no effort on your part at all. This is a 'write my code for me' request which is likely to be closed because of it. The code should also be in the question in case jsFiddle goes down

Comment: Believe me i'm struggeling with this problem for some time now. But for the sake of a minimal example i stripped all those JS from the fiddle :) Good point regarding the code. But not to swamp the question I left the code out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the Intersection Observer. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

However, please checkout: 
https://caniuse.com/#search=intersectionObserver

--- But there are polyfills

Or perhaps a css wizard can come up with a better solution :)

*edit
actually, you can do it with a bit of css... It's not perfect, but a step in a better direction

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav {
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! never heard of position: sticky! https://jsfiddle.net/93eza485/124/ works as expected

Comment: The only thing needed change in your answer was setting the top:0 to `top: 100px` to keep it sticky